# How do I strip tailing space?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

How do I strip the trailing space in between the comma delimited columns?

**CODE**

```
for line in csv_file:
    if pattern.search(str(line)):
        print (line[0],',',line[1],',',line[2],',',line[3])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
HOME , GOODS , 36 , 118
HOME , GOODS , 31 , 121
```

Comment: `print(', '.join(line))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below:

```
for line in csv_file:
    if pattern.search(str(line)):
        print (line[0],',',line[1],',',line[2],',',line[3], sep='')
```